# Hibernate: сохранение осиротившей коллекции

Tags: hibernate

В текущем проекте пришлось сделать поисковый движок на <strike>коленке</strike> SQL-базе. Сейчас у меня есть такая схема:

```
<active_proxy_view>
id     | entity | started at | expired at
<uuid> | <json> | <date>     | <date>

<archive_proxy_view>
id     | entity | started at | expired at
<uuid> | <json> | <date>     | <date>

<metadata_reference>
entity_type | entity_id | metadata_key | metadata_value
proxy       | <uuid>    | visitors     | 13
proxy       | <uuid>    | trial        | yarr

<tracking_reference>
entity_type | entity_id | tracked_domain | tracked_type | tracked_id 
proxy       | <uuid>    | campaign       | carnival     | halloween'16
```

Это все позволяет мне делать выборки следующего типа "найти все действующие прокси, соответствующие хэллоуину 16, начавшиеся после часа Х, у которых было по тринадцать посетителей и у которых был триальный доступ":

```
SELECT v.entity FROM active_proxy_view AS v
  INNER JOIN metadata_reference AS m1 
    ON m1.entity_type = 'proxy' AND m1.entity_id = '?uuid' 
      AND m1.metadata_key = 'visitors' AND m1.metadata_value = '13'
  INNER JOIN metadata_reference AS m2 
    ON m2.entity_type = 'proxy' AND m2.entity_id = '?uuid' 
      AND m2.metadata_key = 'trial' AND m2.metadata_value = 'yarr'
  INNER JOIN tracking_reference AS t1 
    ON t1.entity_type = 'proxy' AND t1.entity_id = '?uuid' 
      AND t1.tracking_domain = 'campaign' AND t1.tracked_type = 'carnival'
      AND t1.tracked_id = 'halloween\'16'
  WHERE started_at > '?hourX'
```

so far so good. проблемы начинаются с текущим стэком, потому что все реализовано через spring и hibernate. В результате у меня получается, что записи из индекс-таблиц (tracking_reference, metadata_reference) имеют по две связанные записи во view-таблицах, а Hibernate при удалении записи из хотя бы одной таблицы удаляет связанные коллекции, обесточивая таким образом вторую таблицу. В данный момент это выглядит так:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class ProxyViewEntryTemplate {

    ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {})
    @Cascade({})
    @JoinColumn(name = MetadataRef.REFERENCE_ID_COLUMN_NAME)
    @Where(clause = "entity_type = 'proxy'")
    @SQLDeleteAll(sql = "DELETE FROM metadata_reference WHERE entity_id = ? and entity_type = 'proxy'")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.NO_ACTION)
    private Collection<MetadataReference> metadata = new ArrayList<>();
```

И все равно даже с такими обвязками гибернейт норовит удалить мои записи из индекс-таблиц, а без указания `@OneToMany` я не могу обойтись, потому что иначе spring specification / criteria api не смогут работать с джойнами. Я могу спастись путем указания белиберды в `@SQLDeleteAll` (просто добавить `WHERE 0 = 1`), но это какой-то очень костыльный шаг. Есть ли нормальные способы запретить гибернейту удалять связанные сущности?

Comment: Может быть, конфликтуют аннотации SQLDeleteAll и OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.NO_ACTION). Я, правда, никогда такими не пользовался, но похоже на то, что @OnDelete запрещает удалять, при этом SQLDeleteAll сообщает как удалять; что выберет Hibernate - неясно. Насчёт "criteria api не смогут работать с джойнами" - можно использовать методы NativeQuery и писать выборку на чистом SQL, а в методе указывать маппинг конечной сущности - (sql, Entity.class). При этом не требуется маппить таблицы из SQL-запроса в конечной сущности.

Comment: @bobzer native sql вообще не вариант. Вариант с одним OnDelete попробую

Comment: @bobzer судя по тем тестам, которые успел прогнать (у  меня сейчас под рукой только очень медленная машина), ничего не изменилось.